# Flow in a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

It's easy, but I don't know how to calcule the flow $\iint_S{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}$ of the Field ${\bf F}(x,y,z)=\langle y^2,xz,2z\rangle$ through de surface $z=1-x^2-y^2$, $z\geq 0$ whose normal vector points up.

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck?